# Registering in Discovery Service for multiple IPs

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

We are using Netflix OSS in our current project which is about to go live within a few weeks. Everything was good until last week. services were getting registered in discovery, the gateway was able to route traffic to required services, the portal was working fine. But when a backup NIC card is installed in each of the servers. When I am restarting the services, the services are getting registered with 2nd nat IP address (10.1.220.125), instead of the hostname (earlier it used to be). I searched google and found many configurations, but when I applied I am not getting the successful/expected result. One such configuration is as below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - p2p.*
```

Here is my application.yml file of the discovery server.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.1.115.8:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 30
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 30

zuul.sensitiveHeaders:

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 500000
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - p2p.*
```

When I see the log, I see that discovery-service is being registered like below:

```
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/10.1.220.125:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=false)
DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY-SERVICE/10.1.220.125:discovery-service:8761 - registration status: 204
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/10.1.220.125:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=true)
```

Where 10.1.220.125 is the new nat IP.

Earlier I used to get the message in log when there was only one nat IP (10.1.115.8) and no backup IP:

```
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=false)
DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 - registration status: 204
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=true)
```

Where KOLSRV1 is the server host name having IP 10.1.115.8 and 10.1.220.125.

How can I register my services with host name instead of IP?

We are using Dalston.SR1 version of spring cloud.

> Edited: With verion Greenwich.RC2

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  environment: prod
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.1.115.8:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 30
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 30
    hostname: KOLSRV1
    ip-address: 10.1.115.8
    preferIpAddress: false
    #preferredNic: bond0
    #forceHostAddress: 10.1.115.8

zuul.sensitiveHeaders:

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 500000

spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - p2p.*
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Request execution failed with message: A message body reader for Java class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and Java type class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found
DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY-SERVICE/10.1.220.125:discovery-service:8761 - was unable to send heartbeat!
```

For your reference, I am providing the ifconfig details of the server.

```
[user@KOLSRV1 ~]$ ifconfig
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.115.8  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast 10.1.115.127
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 976056244  bytes 249957809358 (232.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 193559
        TX packets 937501062  bytes 243749426487 (227.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

em1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 975667166  bytes 249931945975 (232.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 193559
        TX packets 937501062  bytes 243749426487 (227.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

em2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:41  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

em3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16

em4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:3f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 23915308  bytes 7603519514 (7.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23915308  bytes 7603519514 (7.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0a:f7:e7:88:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 389078  bytes 25863383 (24.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.220.125  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.1.221.255
        ether 00:0a:f7:f3:03:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 81021  bytes 14512406 (13.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196820  bytes 265515182 (253.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:ad:3c:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[user@KOLSRV1 ~]$
```

> Update 2

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>discovery-service</artifactId>
    <name>discovery-service</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <finalName>discovery-service</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>application.yml</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.sample.DiscoveryServiceApplication</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${argLine} -noverify</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-service
```

MainApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dalston is no longer supported BTW. Spring Cloud by default uses the hostname if it can. In your case it looks like it can not be resolved. There is also an option to ignore networks similar to interfaces.

Comment: I know Dalston is not supported, but there is no harm in it to use. Why it cannot be resolved? I tried with eureka.instance.hostname= KOLSRV1 also. 
 https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-prefer-ip-address but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what to say if setting hostname doesn't work. I mentioned Dalston, because if there is a bug, it may have been fixed in later code and if we fix anything it would go there.

Comment: ok. I will try moving from Dalston to Greenwich.RELEASE and check...

Comment: @spencergibb I have moved to greenwich.releae version. Still facing the same issue. This time, I have changed the configuration of application.yml  . Kindly suggest. I am getting weird result this time. Kindly check the Edit section of my original post.

Comment: RC2 is a release candidate, SR1 is the latest. That's a very different error that has nothing to do with networks. What version of spring boot are you using? It may be useful to post your dependencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192682/discussion-between-swarup-saha-and-spencergibb).

Comment: @spencergibb I have added dependency and other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@spencergib, I found the solution.

In /etc/hosts file I put the entry like,

```
KOLSRV1   10.1.220.125
```

Now the services are getting registered in discovery services using name instead of IP.

```
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=false)
DiscoveryClient_DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 - registration status: 204
Registered instance DISCOVERY-SERVICE/KOLSRV1:discovery-service:8761 with status UP (replication=true)
```

Thanks..